# Button is not performing any action

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I'm new to coding and I couldn't able to find the bug which is causing the problem
Don't know why when I click on a button it's not performing any operation. Can't locate any error in onclicklistner.It supposes to give me the option to choose an image from the gallery when I click on the choose button rather when I click on Choose button it doesn't do anything also not give any error.

Java code :

```
package com.vshine.neuron;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.vshine.neuron.testing.R;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.IOException;

public class imageupload extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button btn1 , btn2;
TextView tv;
EditText edt;
ImageView img;
private final static int IMG_REQUEST =1;
private Bitmap bitmap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_imageupload);

        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btnupload);
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btnchose);
        //tv = findViewById(R.id.textview);
        edt = findViewById(R.id.edit);
        img = findViewById(R.id.imgview);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId())
        {

            case R.id.btnchose:

                break;
        }
    }

    private void selectImage()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent,IMG_REQUEST);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==IMG_REQUEST && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data !=null)
        {
            Uri path = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),path);
                img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                edt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here Is the XML Code for layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.vshine.neuron.imageupload">

    <!--<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="lang and lat"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/textview"/>-->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/imgview"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter a Name"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/edit"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Upload"
        android:id="@+id/btnupload"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose image"
        android:id="@+id/btnchose"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your onClick method needs to call the selectImage method.

Comment: You are doing nothing on button click. That's why nothing is happening.

Comment: your onclick method is empty in fact, you didn't write there what you want it to do when clicked. Why are you surprised that it does nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to call Your `selectImage()` method inside `onClick()` method

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId())
        {

            case R.id.btnchose:
                selectImage();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanku its worked and was a very silly mistake by me.

Answer (score 5):

Check this. If `Toast` is working, then you have correctly implemented the listener

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch(v.getId())
{
 case R.id.btnchose:
       Toast.makeText(this, "Caleed or not", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this!

```
package com.vshine.neuron;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.vshine.neuron.testing.R;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.IOException;

public class imageupload extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button btn1 , btn2;
TextView tv;
EditText edt;
ImageView img;
private final static int IMG_REQUEST =1;
private Bitmap bitmap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_imageupload);

        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btnupload);
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btnchose);
        //tv = findViewById(R.id.textview);
        edt = findViewById(R.id.edit);
        img = findViewById(R.id.imgview);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId())
        {

            case R.id.btnchose:
                   selectImage();
             //do what you want
                break;
        }
    }

    private void selectImage()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent,IMG_REQUEST);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==IMG_REQUEST && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data !=null)
        {
            Uri path = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),path);
                img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                edt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add `;` after `selectImage()`

Comment: Thanku its worked and was a very silly mistake by me

Comment: @Umair if its solve your problem kindly upvote it and mark it as solution 
happy coding :)

Comment: At Stack Exchange, asking questions is a privilege, not a right. If a user cannot demonstrate, after asking a reasonable number of questions, that their contributions are making the site better (or at very least, not making it worse) then they will be blocked from asking further questions until they have demonstrated their ability to contribute positively.

Answer (score 2):

Add selectImage to `onClick` method like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId())
    {

        case R.id.btnchose:
            selectImage();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Invoke `selectImage()` method in your code:

```
switch (v.getId())
    {

        case R.id.btnchose:
            selectImage();
            break;
    }
```